# htaccess read whitespaces "was not found on this server"

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a little problem. I'm using htaccess for more userfriendly url's but when i add some whitespaces in URL it gives me the next error:

```
The requested URL /capitole/Limba Engleza was not found on this server.
```

My htaccess code looks like that:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule nota.jpg php/img_nota.php [R=301]
RewriteRule ^login login.php
RewriteRule ^recuperare recuperare.php
RewriteRule ^inregistrare inregistrare.php
RewriteRule ^/?([\sa-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(/?([a-z0-9=]+)(/=)?([a-z0-9=]+)?)?$ index.php?page=$1&par1=$3&par2=$5 [NC,L]
</ifModule>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your 2nd segment doesn't accept `space` modify it to read as follows.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([\sa-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(/?([\sA-Za-z0-9=]+)(/=)?([a-z0-9=]+)?)?$ index.php?page=$1&par1=$3&par2=$5 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Although the rule might be correct, whitespaces still not being allowed in URLs.

Comment: white space gets converted to `%20` with modern day browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The URL can not contain whitespaces. Whitespaces in URLs are encoded using the percentage (%).

If it is a query string (after ?) it's common to use the operator `+` (for example: `big+ships`).
If the string is in the path of the URL, then `%20` is used (for example: `big%20ships`).

As detailed on the RFC: [rfc2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)

> The space character is excluded because significant spaces may
>   disappear and insignificant spaces may be introduced when URI are
>   transcribed or typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-
>   processing programs.  Whitespace is also used to delimit URI in many
>   contexts.
>
> space   =  US-ASCII coded character 20 hexadecimal